# getting a null error when using today's dates and yesterday's dates

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have run into a scenario that is giving me a null error and do not know how to fix it - can't even figure out where the null error is throwing.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reportFreeCooling(
  IN fromDate VARCHAR (50),
  IN toDate   VARCHAR (50),
  IN timeZone VARCHAR (50)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE startDate VARCHAR (50);
  DECLARE endDate   VARCHAR (50);
  DECLARE startDateOriginal VARCHAR (50);
  DECLARE mylogID   INT;
  DECLARE myItemId varchar (50);
  DECLARE myItemId2 varchar (50);
  DECLARE xHours varchar (50);
  DECLARE endHoursNull varchar(50);
  DECLARE endHoursNotNull varchar (50);
  DECLARE firstRow INT;
  DECLARE firstRowDate varchar(50);
  DECLARE minRowDate varchar (50);
  DECLARE minRow int;

  SET startDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate/1000);
  SET endDate   = FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate/1000);
  SET startDateOriginal = FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate/1000);


  SET mylogID   = (SELECT logID FROM logs WHERE details LIKE 'FCT%' LIMIT 1);
  SET myItemID = (SELECT i.itemId FROM items i  WHERE i.name LIKE '%KW PRE%');
  SET myItemID2 = (SELECT i.itemId FROM items i  WHERE  i.name LIKE '%KW STA%');

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempTable3 CASCADE;



  SET @sql = NULL;
  SET @sql = CONCAT(
 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable3 AS (SELECT
    @row := @row + 1 AS rownum,
    a.logId,a.name AS Type,
    L1.recordId,
    L2.recordId AS next_recordId,
    L1.completed,
    L2.completed AS next_completed,
    L3.completed AS first_completed,
    L1.activityId AS activityJoin,
    L2.activityId AS next_activityId,
    IF(L1.activityId = L2.activityId, 1, NULL) AS isError,
     CASE
        when a.name LIKE ''%Enable%'' THEN time_to_sec(timediff(L2.completed, L1.completed)) / 3600
        ELSE NULL
        END AS coolingHours,
     TO_SECONDS(L2.completed) - TO_SECONDS(L1.completed) AS timeInSeconds,
    ((SUBSTR(l.details, INSTR(l.details, '':'') + 1))) AS charge,
    time_to_sec(timediff(''', endDate, ''', ''', startDate, ''')) / 3600 AS totalTimeRange,
    CONVERT_TZ(''', startDate, ''', ''UTC'', ''', timeZone, ''') AS startingDate, 
    CONVERT_TZ(''', endDate, ''', ''UTC'', ''', timeZone, ''') AS endingDate,
    (L1.item', myItemID, ' - L1.item', myItemID2, ') AS itemDifference,
    ((L1.item', myItemID, ' - L1.item', myItemID2, ') * 
        (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(L2.completed, L1.completed))/3600)) AS kwDifference,
    ((L1.item', myItemID, ' - L1.item', myItemID2, ') * (SUBSTR(l.details, INSTR(l.details, '':'') + 1))) AS cost,
    ((((L1.item', myItemID, ' - L1.item', myItemID2, ') * (SUBSTR(l.details, INSTR(l.details,'':'') + 1)))
    * (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(L2.completed, L1.completed)) / 3600))) AS costT,
    DATABASE() AS databaseName, i.itemId ,l.details
FROM
    (SELECT @row:=0)R,
    (SELECT T1.completed
         , (SELECT MIN(T2.completed) 
            FROM log',mylogID, ' T2
            WHERE T2.completed > T1.completed) AS next_completed
         , (SELECT MAX(T2.completed) 
            FROM log',mylogID, ' T2
            WHERE T2.completed < T1.completed) AS frst_completed
    FROM log',mylogID, ' T1
    ORDER BY T1.completed
     )TimeOrder
        LEFT JOIN log', mylogID, ' L1 ON (L1.completed = TimeOrder.completed)
        LEFT JOIN log', mylogID, ' L2 ON (L2.completed = TimeOrder.next_completed)
        LEFT JOIN log', mylogID, ' L3 ON (L3.completed = TimeOrder.frst_completed)
        LEFT JOIN activities a ON L1.activityId = a.activityId
        LEFT JOIN logs l ON a.logId = l.logId
        LEFT JOIN items i ON l.logId = i.logId AND i.name LIKE ''%KW PRE%'' 
   )order by L1.completed');  

     PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 

    /* sets next row hours when date is after startdate and first is null */
    SET @startDate = (SELECT MIN(completed) FROM tempTable3 WHERE coolingHours is NULL AND 
        completed BETWEEN startDate AND endDate);
    SET @startDate2 = (SELECT MAX(completed) FROM tempTable3 WHERE completed < @startDate);
    SET startDate = @startDate2;

   /* sets end hours when last row is enabled and next_completed is greater than end date */
   SET @endHoursNotNull = (SELECT MAX(completed) AS maxCompletedDateAndCoolingHoursNotNull FROM tempTable3 WHERE coolingHours is NOT NULL AND 
        completed BETWEEN startDate AND endDate);
   SET endHoursNotNull= @endHoursNotNull;
   SET @endHoursNull = (SELECT MAX(completed) AS maxCompletedAndCoolingHoursNull FROM tempTable3 WHERE coolingHours is NULL AND 
        completed BETWEEN startDate AND endDate);
   SET endHoursNull = @endHoursNull;

      /* sets first row hours when date is after startdate and first enabled */
    SET firstRowDate = (SELECT MIN(completed) FROM tempTable3);
    IF firstRowDate > startDateOriginal THEN SET startDateOriginal = firstRowDate; END IF;
   SET @newcoolingHours = (SELECT (time_to_sec(timediff(next_completed, startDateOriginal)) / 3600) AS newCoolingHours 
        FROM tempTable3 WHERE completed >= startDateOriginal 
                          AND completed BETWEEN startDate AND endDate LIMIT 1);
   SET xHours = @newCoolingHours;

   SET minRowDate = (SELECT MIN(completed) FROM tempTable3 WHERE completed BETWEEN startDate AND endDate LIMIT 1 );
   SET minRow = (SELECT MIN(rowNum)FROM tempTable3 WHERE completed BETWEEN startDate AND endDate LIMIT 1 );
   /* set first row number and hours for when first row in log(itemId) is greater then startdate */

  SET @sqlTemp = NULL;
  SET @sqlTemp = 
   CONCAT(
  'SELECT   rowNum,l.completed,l.next_completed,l.first_completed,startingDate,endingDate,Type,itemDifference,
        ''',startDateOriginal,''' AS oStartDate, ''',startDate,'''  as startDate,
   (time_to_sec(timediff(next_completed, completed)) / 3600)AS cHours, 
   CASE
        WHEN (''',startDateOriginal,''' > ''',startDate,''' AND Type LIKE ''%Enable%'' AND rowNum = ''',minRow,''')
            THEN (time_to_sec(timediff(next_completed, ''',startDateOriginal,''')) / 3600)
        WHEN (DAYOFYEAR(completed) = DAYOFYEAR(''',startDate,'''))
            THEN ''',xHours,'''
        WHEN (''',endHoursNotNull,''' > ''',endHoursNull,''' AND next_completed > ''',endDate,''' )
            THEN ((time_to_sec(timediff(''',endDate,''', completed))) / 3600)
        ELSE coolingHours
    END AS coolingHours,
    isError,charge,totalTimeRange,
    l.logId,databaseName,i.name,l.itemId,
    CASE 
        WHEN (''',startDateOriginal,''' > ''',startDate,''' AND Type LIKE ''%Enable%'' AND rowNum = ''',minRow,''')
            THEN (itemDifference*(time_to_sec(timediff(next_completed, ''',startDateOriginal,''')) / 3600))
        WHEN (DAYOFYEAR(completed) = DAYOFYEAR(''',startDate,'''))
            THEN (''',xHours,'''* itemDifference)
        WHEN (''',endHoursNotNull,''' > ''',endHoursNull,''' AND next_completed > ''',endDate,''' )
            THEN (itemDifference*((time_to_sec(timediff(''',endDate,''', completed))) / 3600))
        ELSE kwDifference
    END AS kwDifference,cost, 
   CASE
        WHEN (''',startDateOriginal,''' > ''',startDate,''' AND Type LIKE ''%Enable%'' AND rowNum = ''',minRow,''')
            THEN ((time_to_sec(timediff(next_completed, ''',startDateOriginal,''')) / 3600)* cost)
        WHEN  (DAYOFYEAR(completed) = DAYOFYEAR(''',startDate,'''))
            THEN (''',xHours,''' * cost)
        WHEN  (''',endHoursNotNull,''' > ''',endHoursNull,''' AND next_completed > ''',endDate,''' )
            THEN (((time_to_sec(timediff(''',endDate,''', completed))) / 3600) * cost)
        ELSE costT
    END AS costT,l.details,timeInSeconds

  FROM tempTable3 l
   inner join items i ON l.logId = i.logId AND i.name LIKE ''%KW PRE%'' 
   WHERE l.itemId = ''',myItemId,''' 
          AND completed BETWEEN ''', startDate, ''' AND ''', endDate, '''

 '); 



PREPARE stmtTemp FROM @sqlTemp;
 EXECUTE stmtTemp;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtTemp;

 DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable3;

END //


DELIMITER ;
```

I do know that is has to do with the last row of data and the next_completed being null

last rows of data

```
row Num completed   next_completed  first_completed starting Date   ending Date
28  12/28/2013 6:30:35 PM   12/29/2013 12:07:19 AM  12/27/2013 11:22:54 PM  12/31/1969 10:00:00 PM  12/31/2013 10:00:00 PM
29  12/29/2013 12:07:19 AM  12/29/2013 8:56:58 AM   12/28/2013 6:30:35 PM   12/31/1969 10:00:00 PM  12/31/2013 10:00:00 PM
30  12/29/2013 8:56:58 AM   12/31/2013 11:27:40 PM  12/29/2013 12:07:19 AM  12/31/1969 10:00:00 PM  12/31/2013 10:00:00 PM
31  12/31/2013 11:27:40 PM  (null)  12/29/2013 8:56:58 AM   12/31/1969 10:00:00 PM  12/31/2013 10:00:00 PM
```

Comment: Those are NOT valid mysql date/time strings and WILL cause nulls/invalid dates in any "math" you don them. They **MUST** be in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format to be treated as native by mysql.

Comment: They work for EVERY other time frame calculation so that I do not think that is the problem.